# How to make RowNumber (local report) work in this case?

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting, rdlc, localreport

I have a Report with a group, each group has some different rows. Using `RowNumber([group_name])` will return the last row number in the group and `RowNumber(nothing)` will return the row number running through all the rows in the group. I want to have some kind of `RowNumber` which returns the group number instead. For example, here is the sample table in the report:

```
//This is grouped by Name
Order          Name            Item
------------------------------------------
 1              A              Item 1 of A 
                               Item 2 of A
------------------------------------------
 2              B              Item 1 of B
                               Item 2 of B
                               Item 3 of B
------------------------------------------
 3              C              Item 1 of C
------------------------------------------
 4              D              Item 1 of D
```

The above table is what I want, however if using `RowNumber("NameGroup")` for the column `Order`, the result will be:

```
Order          Name            Item
------------------------------------------
 2              A              Item 1 of A 
                               Item 2 of A
------------------------------------------
 3              B              Item 1 of B
                               Item 2 of B
                               Item 3 of B
------------------------------------------
 1              C              Item 1 of C
------------------------------------------
 1              D              Item 1 of D
```

If using `RowNumber(nothing)` for the column `Order`, the result will be:

```
Order          Name            Item
------------------------------------------
 2              A              Item 1 of A 
                               Item 2 of A
------------------------------------------
 5              B              Item 1 of B
                               Item 2 of B
                               Item 3 of B
------------------------------------------
 6              C              Item 1 of C
------------------------------------------
 7              D              Item 1 of D
```

Preparing data for the `Order` column is OK but I want to use some support of Local Report for this kind of work (numbering the row). In fact, I want to number the group in this case, not the row. Could you please give me some solution for this?

Your help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at using the [RunningValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159136%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) function for this, something like:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Name.Value, CountDistinct, "DataSet1")
```

You might have to play with the **Scope** parameter to get the correct **Scope** for your desired results.

Comment: Sounds interesting but my report threw an exception (which is very general): `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException`, Any idea?

Comment: Wow, it works like a charm. The exception was thrown by another expression of my group Variable. Thank you so much. You saved my life +1 and accept right now! ha ha :))